# DocuSign API: Populating dynamic fields

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to have fields in my template be populated when I call the post request of my API, currently I am getting the template which I created in DocuSign's Template creator. But I need to be able dynamically change these fields contents.

How do I find the custom field which I created? I am currently using `TextCustomField`. The only thing I can see which would find the custom field is `FieldId` but there is no option on the website to set or find one. So I am not sure what to do from here. Here is a code snippet to how I have tried it so far, to no success.

I a junior developer and I am new to docusign, and I feel that the documentation leaves a lot to be desired.

```
         CustomFields cf = new CustomFields();
         cf.TextCustomFields = new List<TextCustomField>();
         TextCustomField tcf = new TextCustomField();
         
         tcf.FieldId = "001";
         tcf.Name = "test";
         tcf.Value = "NewValueFor test_field_1";
         cf.TextCustomFields.Add(tcf);
         env.CustomFields = cf;
```

I set the data label on the website to 001.

[image]

Comment: To confirm, are you trying to populate an Envelope Custom Field (hidden metadata, locked at the point of sending, signer never interacts) or a Text Tab (appears on the document to be signed, may or may not be accessible by the signer)?
https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-trenches-tabs-and-custom-fields

Comment: Yes, but I have created the template using the website, so I am having trouble finding the custom fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's been a misunderstanding in DocuSign vocabulary. Your screenshot shows a "field", which in eSignature API terms is a "tab". The `TextCustomField` object you currently have would be used to populate an Envelope Custom Field - not what you're currently trying to do.

If you've placed that tab on your template, then you can populate it's value by creating a `TextTab` object and assigning it to your `signer`'s list of tabs like so. The `TabLabel` aligns with the web console's `Name` parameter, and the `Value` is what you want to populate it with.

```
        Text exampleTab1 = new Text //Create the Tab definition
        {
            Value = "Example Value",
            TabLabel = "test_field_1",
        };

        Signer signer1 = new Signer //Create a Signer
        {
            Email = signerEmail,
            Name = signerName,
            RecipientId = "1",
            RoutingOrder = "1",
        };

        Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs //Assign Tab to Signer
        {
            TextTabs = new List<Text> { exampleTab1 }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Although if it isn't actually called a custom field the website shouldn't say it's a custom field. The functionality for DocuSign is great, but the documentation is one of the worst I've used.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can leverage the C# feature called LINQ, you need to add the following namespace to your class:

```
using System.Linq;
```

And then you can find your objects with this code:

```
var mycustomField = cf.TextCustomFields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FieldId == "MYIDENTIFICATOR");
```

Comment: I have no way of setting the FieldId on the website in my template, the only option I have is Data Label, so how would this integrate with that?

Comment: In the sample code you provided, you are setting the custom field id: tcf.FieldId = "001";

Comment: Yes but I have created a Custom field on the website, which has no option for a field id.

Comment: My Issue is : I have created a 'Docutemplate1' with a custom data field '{{UserID}}', Now, I want to create a unique document each time using the 'Docutemplate1' with the datafield value dynamically inserted at run time.
I am looking for Specific postman Rest API calls